# regex to match strict n character include new line character

Tags: regex

I want to validate my input records coming one by one from file. And my file can contain 10,000 to 20,000 records

Record can have only (capital aplphabets, -, dot, spaces and numbers) only. And record ends up with new line character. It could be one of them (\n or \r\n)

I want regex to match record only having above five parameters with including new character of both type (\n or \r\n). If record contains other character from I've mentioned should not be matched.

I've tried this regex.

```
[A-Z\d\- ]{120}\s+$
```

lets take an example for 10 characters.

```
1) Input
AAAA12.0 A\nor\r\n

Regex should match for given input(1) because of exact ten characters plus new line character(one is possible at a time)

2)Input
AA-A13.0 AAA\nor\r\n

Regex should match for given input(2) because number of characters are more than 10
```

But this regex fails sometime. Any suggestion on this regex to improve and make it more strict on my five requirements ?

Comment: It looks good and it's probably a case of things not yet taken in to account. This site is a good testing ground: https://regex101.com/

Comment: What is the code behind it? If you need to match dots, too, why not include them into the pattern? Also, you check for the end of string (line?) with `$`, and you do not use `^`  (start of string/line) anchor. Without an exact sample input text it is not that clear how to help you.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, I'm using dot because in record decimal values also come. DO you think so..this regex is fine to match record only 120 characters plus new line character (\n or \r\n) ?

Comment: On what specific cases does your regex fail? If your regex engine supports it, I would use the `\p{Lu}` upper-case character class that is unicode-aware instead of `[A-Z]` (see http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html).

Comment: Sorry, the question is unclear to me. Your regex does not match line breaks, btw. You would need `\r?\n` at the end.

Comment: example input and output

Comment: What is the programming language? What is the code behind this regex (how are you using it)?

Comment: For 10 char limit, I'd use [`^[A-Z.0-9 -]{1,10}\r?\n`](https://regex101.com/r/32rh9K/2). Still, not knowing the regex engine and how you use the regex it is still very unclear.

Answer (score 0):

This expression:

```
^[-.A-Z \d]*\r?$
```

Matches if the entire line consists of only hyphen, dot, capital A-Z, space, and digit, and ends with `\n` or optionally `\r\n`.

Comment: @Luv2code..and how can use this regex to restrict input data not to have more than 120 characters.  If there are 121 characters plus new line character..regex should not work

Comment: Okay, that was not in your original  specification. To restrict to not more than 120 characters, replace the asterisk with `{0,120}` (although, the zero can be omitted with most regex engines: `{,120}`).

Comment: @Luv2code..its not working when more than 120 characters come in my input record. Its allowing them.

Comment: As long as you have the line anchors, this should only match lines that have zero to 120 of the specified characters followed by an optional CR, them LF. Show me what you're using that's

Comment: That's matching lines greater than 120 + CR + LF.